# Add note to custom data record in code

Tags: acumatica

I was searching for a solution to add a note to a database row I am creating in a custom table.  I found the solution below from Ruslan for accessing the noteid, but I don't understand how this would be used to add a note to the row.  I have all the code to create the row, I just need the attributes or function call to actually attach the text of the note to the row.

==================================================================

To have Note record automatically created when a new parent record gets saved, one should invoke the static PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID(PXCache cache, object data) method when the parent record is inserted in the cache.

For example, to have Note record automatically created when a new Stock Item gets saved, you should subscribe to RowInserted handler for the InventoryItem DAC and call PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID(...):

```
public class InventoryItemMaintExt : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    public void InventoryItem_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
    {
        var noteCache = Base.Caches[typeof(Note)];
        var oldDirty = noteCache.IsDirty;
        PXNoteAttribute.GetNoteID<InventoryItem.noteID>(sender, e.Row);
        noteCache.IsDirty = oldDirty;
    }
}
```

The code snippet above can be incorporated into almost any custom BLC with a couple simple changes to replace InventoryItem with a custom DAC.

---

After implementing Gabriel's suggestions:

I do not seem to get any note in the database.  The code compiles and runs fine, but the notes are not generated as far as I can tell.  The note id is set in my table, but no data appears in the note table. Please take a look at my code and let me know what needs to change. Also, how do I get the note column into a grid, or does it automatically become available when it is done correctly?

Database field definition:

```
[NoteID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
```

DAC field:

```
    #region NoteID
    public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    protected Guid? _NoteID;
    [PXNote()]
    public virtual Guid? NoteID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._NoteID;
        }
        set
        {
            this._NoteID = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Code to create record:

```
    private static bool acumaticaException(Exception e, EDImportExceptionMaint excpMaint, LingoRet850 res850)
    {
        excpMaint.Clear();
        var except = new EDImportExcept();
        except.ExceptReason = "U";
        except.Active = true;

        <...field assignments...>

        except.OrderNbr = "";
        PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(excpMaint.Exception.Cache, excpMaint.Exception.Current, 
            ((PX.Data.PXOuterException)e).InnerMessages[0] + "-" + e.Message);
        excpMaint.Exception.Insert(except);
        excpMaint.Actions.PressSave();
        return true;
  }
```

Comment: i believe that just generates the noteid record - not note text if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the code to establish the note record/text and any other attributes so as to have the note indication on the grid for my screen and make it able to be displayed in a popup by clicking on it.   Just guessing, but to I need to use the code above to generate the note record and then update it?  I thought there would be specific functions or attributes to set the text.

Comment: The problem is that you are setting the Note *before* actually inserting the `except` record into the cache. Insert it and then set the note and it shall work. I also suspect it will work if you just replace `excpMaint.Exception.Current` with `except`, but still think it's better to insert the record first (it doesn't hit the DB until you do `PressSave()`)

Comment: Merci Beaucoup!!  Makes total sense but just one of those little concepts you can miss.  Just one quick question.  Is it best to set the note before the PressSave or after?

Comment: Also, I use a dynamic DAC in a graph to display data from multiple tables in a processing grid.  Do I have to get the note from the custom table and then set it to the dynamic DAC so it will show?  Is there anything special to get the note into the grid?

Comment: I have everything working except showing the notes column in the custom grid.  I never really looked at it, but other standard processing screens (data all from 1 table w/normal DAC) do not show the notes column either.  There must be some setup option I am not doing.

Comment: You should set the note before PressSave. If you want the note to display in the grid you can do it a few different ways, the simplest would probably be to join with the Note table in your view (LeftJoin<Note<On...).

Comment: Thanks again!  I thought just the note id in the main table would automatically do it.  I will try the join.

Comment: It is possible the PXNote attribute on the NoteId defines a dynamic field that you can directly bind to the grid but I don’t recall seeing that. Your best bet is the LefJoin. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Have not tried it yet.  Sidetracked on another issue (sure you know how that happens).  I will reply if I have an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the note of a record, use the `SetNote()`static function of `PXNoteAttribute`

```
PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(Base.Item.Cache, Base.Item.Current, "Hello, World!");
```

Calling `SetNote` will also take care of adding the Note record if it doesn't exist, so you don't have to call `GetNoteID` before setting the note value as in your question.

P.S. There is also a `GetNote` function which allows you to retrieve the current value of the note:

```
string note = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(Base.Item.Cache, Base.Item.Current);
```

Comment: See added questions in description. Note still not working.

Comment: Please see comments above. I may have put them in the wrong place? Having problem getting note column to show.